# Colision detection with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

I am trying to implement a Collision detection algorithm but it is not working
I have an array of objects called sprites
The objects have x and y centre points and radius or width and height propertys.
My function removes objects from the array if they have collided.
When I run it all objects are removed how ever.
How do I fix this?
My code:

```
function colision() {
  for (var i = 0; i < sprites.length; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < sprites.length; j++) {
      if (i == j) {
        j++
      }
      var spr1 = sprites[i],
        spr2 = sprites[j]

      if (spr1.shape == "circle" && spr2.shape == "circle") {
        if (spr1.r + spr2.r >= Math.sqrt((spr1.x - spr2.x) ** 2 + (spr1.y - spr2.y) ** 2)) {
          spr2.noise.stop();
          sprites.splice(j, 1);
          spr1.noise.stop();
          sprites.splice(i, 1);
          --i
          continue;
        }
      } else if (spr1.shape == "rect" && spr2.shape == "rect") {
        spr2.noise.stop();
        sprites.splice(j, 1)
        spr1.noise.stop();
        sprites.splice(i, 1)
          --i
        continue;
      }
      if (spr1.shape == "circle" && spr2.shape == "rect") {
        var gradient = Math.abs((spr1.y - spr2.y) / ((spr1.x - spr2.x) || 0.00000001))
        var point = {}
        if (spr1.x > spr2.x && spr1.y > spr2.y) {
          point.x = spr1.x - spr1.r / gradient;
          point.y = spr1.y - spr1.r / gradient;
          if (point.x < (spr2.x + spr2.w / 2) && point.y < (spr2.y + spr.h / 2)) {
            spr2.noise.stop();
            sprites.splice(j, 1);
            spr1.noise.stop();
            sprites.splice(i, 1);
            --i;
            continue;
          };
        }
        if (spr1.x < spr2.x && spr1.y > spr2.y) {
          point.x = spr1.x + spr1.r / gradient;
          point.y = spr1.y - spr1.r / gradient;
          if (point.x > (spr2.x - spr2.w / 2) && point.y < (spr2.y + spr.h / 2)) {
            spr2.noise.stop();
            sprites.splice(j, 1);
            spr1.noise.stop();
            sprites.splice(i, 1);
            --i;
            continue;
          };
        } else if (spr1.x < spr2.x && spr1.y < spr2.y) {
          point.x = spr1.x + spr1.r / gradient;
          point.y = spr1.y + spr1.r / gradient;
          if (point.x > (spr2.x - spr.w / 2) && point.y > (spr2.y - spr2.h / 2)) {
            spr2.noise.stop();
            sprites.splice(j, 1);
            spr1.noise.stop();
            sprites.splice(i, 1);
            --i;
            continue;
          };
        } else if (spr1.x > spr2.x && spr1.y < spr2.y) {
          point.x = spr1.x - spr1.r / gradient;
          point.y = spr1.y + spr1.r / gradient;
          if (point.x < (spr2.x + spr.w / 2) && point.y > (spr2.y - spr.h / 2)) {
            spr2.noise.stop();
            sprites.splice(j, 1);
            spr1.noise.stop();
            sprites.splice(i, 1);
            --i;
            continue;
          };
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to trace the logic on a white paper

Comment: I have, I did so befor writing the function

Comment: There is an error I just noticed, I do not detect If two rectangles collide but this will not effect circles

Comment: Ok I commented it out and nothing is being detected

Comment: I've changed all the continue statements to break to fully escape the j loop and it's still not learning

Comment: Working* not learning.